# Git force pull branch from remote

Tags: git, merge, github, fetch, pull

So I have 2 branches on GitHub: master and branchA. Say I've been working on master and master is ahead by 3 commits or something. So there are commits d, e, and f on master that are not in branchA. Say next that my colleague uploaded branchA to GitHub with commit g. So we have:

```
master: a, b, c, d, e, f
branchA: a, b, c, g
```

Say now I want to switch to branchA and pull exactly what is on GitHub. The issue I'm running into is when I use `git branch branchA` it will automatically use master as my starting position and thus add d,e,f and when I pull branchA I get conflicts as g and d,e,f are not yet compatible.

Is there a way to pull from GitHub such that my local commit log matches that on GitHub? I tried `git pull -f` but that obviously didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should

```
git fetch
```

then inspect what has transpired with something like

```
git log --all --oneline --graph --decorate
```

Now you can merge or rebase the work that was done at the same time. Any branches prefixed with "origin" will be what's on github (assuming that's where you cloned from). Local branches will be coloured differently too.

If you want to work a branch that was pulled down that you haven't worked on yet, check it out and track it in a local branch with

```
git checkout -t origin/someBranch
```

I would only use pull in exceptional cases where I'm merging or rebasing my own work. Depending on what someone else did, I may choose rebasing over merging.

Comment: git checkout -t origin/someBranch worked perfectly. Thanks! (I can't accept answer for another 7 mins, but will do once I can)

Comment: no problem. I hope you understand my point about fetching first, inspecting and then deciding on rebasing or merging depending on the work that was done :)

Comment: I had already fetched everything, I just couldn't figure out how to switch to branch I hadn't created yet without pulling in all my master ones as well. But the -t param worked wonders. I would use log, but there are a few hundred commits I would need to sort through and I'm partially lazy =P

Comment: For sure. `git log` also takes branch names as parameters and you can exclude things like merges etc. It's worth investigating as it can really help decipher a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

```
git fetch origin
git checkout origin/branchA -b <local branch name>
```

This will create a local branch with the name you specify that is an exact replicate of `branchA` on `origin`. If your GitHub remote is named something other than `origin`, adjust accordingly.

You can also just specify the start point with `git branch`:

```
git fetch origin
git branch <local branch name> origin/branchA
git checkout <local branch name>
```

The `-b` flag for `git checkout` just makes things one step shorter if you're planning to check out the branch you're creating anyway.

Furthermore, if you want your local branch name to be identical to the remote branch, there's an even shorter way:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout -t origin/branchA
```

which will create a local `branchA` which matches `origin`'s `branchA`.

Comment: yes I added that shorter way, then you edited and added to your answer :)

Comment: Anything to make a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t mind to lose your own local changes, you can use

```bash
git fetch
git reset --hard origin/$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
```